# My .css file is not working properly under the Asp.net MVC file

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

The included styles take a long time to work. So after adding some style I can not see what look like is

Comment: please prove the necessary details. How you using CSS, where you using it. 
NOTE: Sometimes a browser didn't load the CSS file from the physical path after refresh rather it loads CSS from its cache. So clear some history and cache then reload the page to see the change.

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.